# Table View Not Properly Updating

Tags: objective-c, ios

My project is a large one, and I'm not sure which code snippet is causing the problem, so I'll just describe the problem. I have an initial view that is a `UITableView.` This view has a `navigation bar`, in which one of the buttons is an "`edit`" button. Pressing the "edit" button sends you into a modal view controller in which there is another UITableView. This `UITableView` has the attribute that it is a checklist `table view` (in which multiple items can be selected [checked] or deselected. Once you are finished choosing your items, it saves the array of chosen objects into an `NSUserDefault.` Now, you are back at the original page where the array of things you chose should be displayed on the `UITableView`. I change the array that is feeding the `UITableView` it's data to the array grabbed from the `NSUserDefaults`. I then call `[tableView reloadData]` and nothing changes. I would really appreciate any tips. If you guys think you know what part of the code is causing me grief, please respond and I'll post it. Thanks (and by the way, I know I should be making the main `view controller` the `delegate` of `modal view controllers`). Thanks in advance.

Comment: where do you reload table? in viewWillAppear or ViewDidLoad.

Comment: Are you doing your `synchronize` method on your `NSUserDefaults` before going back to the tableview?

Comment: Is there a method to reload the table?

Comment: The modal view controller releases a notification when the person is done changing and then the method gets called in response to the notification and calls reloadData. This isn't seeming to update it...

Comment: Why you are use notification simply you can reload data into ViewWillAppear.Before this check your array in which you are save changes. if your array not show data it's mean you make mistake at  time save data into NSUserDefault.

Comment: No, the data is saving correctly. The the array is all correct. The only thing is that it doesn't change (the UITableView, I mean) at runtime. If you close out of the application and then reopen it, it shows the new changes. My question I suppose is what method should I call to reload the UITableView at runtime and where should I invoke it?

Comment: Your save data into UserDefault.I'm right?

Comment: Yes, I save the data into NSUserDefaults, then I go back to the other view, and retrieve the data and put it into an array which is then fed into the UITableView.

Comment: Retrieve data and put it into table data array after this reload table,NOTE "this code write into ViewWillAppear".

Comment: When you call reloadData, does it basically recall cellForRowAtIndexPath?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15514/discussion-between-hardeep-singh-and-monkeyanator)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];` after you make changes in the modal view controller.  This will save the changes.

Be sure to update the cell content each time the table row is reloaded.

```
- (void)configureCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    Bleh *data = (Get your data for this row);

    cell.textLabel.text = data.myValue;
    cell.imageView.image = data.myImage;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    [self configureCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: It's saying synchronize is a boolean value.

Comment: Okay, thank you, that helped partly. Now if you make your selections and then close the application, all of your choices show up on the UITableView. How can I make it so that when I dismiss the modal view controller, the UITableView automatically updates?

Comment: You could just reload the table.  Sounds like the checkbox is a custom control.  You could send a notification and then it could update it's state.

Comment: Anything that works will be super appreciated... I'm almost out of my mind trying to fix this dumb problem.

Comment: Put `NSLog(@".. print out row data ..");` inside `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and see if that getting called.  Don't forget to adjust the cell display.

Comment: I did that earlier, and it was calling it again. I'll check one more time. What do you mean adjust the cell display?

Comment: Since the data has changed you will need to change the cells contents.  Basically, you need to change all the data for a cell.  You should separate `cellForRowAtIndexPath` from configuring a cell.  I'll put an example above.

Comment: Erm, I'm a bit confused. In the configureCell method, it shows cell.textLabel.text = DATA. Well, my data would be [currentSports objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

Comment: No, I've already done this, it doesn't work. If you want, I can show you the source code in chat? I just wish this could be fixed.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15515/discussion-between-bbarnhart-and-monkeyanator)

Answer (score 0):

Try to reload your `tableview` on `viewwillappear` , when you back from `modelviewcontroller` method calls

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
[yourTableView reloadData];
}
```